# What is the difference between Google Rest API and Google Apps Script Execution API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

What is the difference? Can you combine Google Apps Script with Google Rest API? Or is the Execution API the alternative?

Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: these are not comparable. op should first understand what REST means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are entirely separate.

The Google REST API's are provided by Google and allow you to interact with their services from an external location. Essentially your code can call code written by Google, to impact Google services.

The Google Apps Script Execution API allows you to expose functions *you* have written in Google Apps Script to be called from an external location. Essentially this allows you to call custom code which is hosted by Google from an external location.

The key difference here is that the Google REST API has nothing to do with Google Apps Script, while the Execution API is all about letting you call Google Apps Script code.

You can certainly mix both in a given project, depending on what you are trying to do. Google Apps Script can even make use of the REST API, although 
that is often not needed.

If you are trying to figure out which one you need, read about Google Apps Script and determine if working in that language is suitable for your project.

If you are planning to work from another language like Python or Java, then you probably need the REST API.   Finally, if you want to work in Python or Java, but call some pieces of code written in Apps Script, then you should look at the Apps Script Execution API.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. So, I have a program created with Google Apps Script and it's an add-on. However, I realize its much better suited to be used in the 'Open With' Tab. I realize I'll have to change some code but I would have to use the Drive API right? Can i connect the GAS code to that API? Sorry, i've been confused and your answer was helpful

Comment: "Entirely separate" - actually the first line in the description of the Execution API is "The Apps Script Execution API is a REST interface".

Comment: Glad the response was helpful.  I don't have any experience developing Drive applications that are accessed via "Open With" so I can onlyguess at your follow up question. You can probably leverage at least some of your Apps Script code, but I'm not sure what the overall solution has to look like. You might need an external component running on a service like the Google App Engine, which could then call some of your Apps Script with the execution API.

Comment: I forgot to mention, you can connect GAS code to the Drive API via the "Advanced Google Services" in the GAS editor, but I'm not sure if that will let you build a complete solution that works with "Open With.." on Drive. I think you'll need an external service to deal with OAuth stuff. Hence my previous comment.

Comment: So if I use a GAS code this doesn't count into the API quote of Google REST API?

Comment: @alexchvrches no, that is not the case. Calls to Google API's (Drive, Gmail, Calendar, etc.) from Apps Script count towards quotas for those products. In addition, there are Apps Script specific limits on many services. This is detailed at the following link, note the section in blue which addresses your specific question. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Answer (score 3):

The [Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/) is a REST API.

There is no such thing as *the* Google REST API since REST is an architecture, not a Google service. Many Google APIs have REST or at least REST-like interfaces.

REST is an acronym for representational state transfer. As per usual it is impossible to explain this without provoking dozens of comments that point out the explanation is wrong or incomplete, so I refer you [to the Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). But important features of REST are that resources are represented by URLs and that different http verbs (get, put, post etc) can evoke different responses from the server for similar resources (which adds purposefully a few constraints, i.e. GET is not supposed to do destructive operations etc.).

So "REST" is a specific way to design an API and Google used this design for the Apps Script Execution API.

Comment: this is a much better answer.

Comment: "As per usual it is impossible to explain this without provoking dozens of comments that point out the explanation is wrong or incomplete"

 You're pretty good at joking.

The OP saw a huge documentation and quickstart for Google App Script, a modern JavaScript API for accessing all the Google Services,
and another huge documentation and quickstart for Google App Script, maybe through REST APIs or the googleapis packages for most programming languages.

Comment: Instead of clearing the confusion on what was asked, you were teaching the defenition of "REST API".
Well and good, except if your answer had some content that answers the original question that was asked.